# Google spreadsheets—sum cells from another row based on a cell value

Tags: google-sheets

My current code is:

```
(SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-(I4:I- 1);COLUMN()-4;4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-4;4)))*( ( J4:J ) / 10 ))))
```

I want to sum cells from `Gx` – `Gy` but range is determed by cell `I4`. My existing code works, but only for one line.

```
=ArrayFormula( if( J4:J = "" ; "" ;
```

So if I put `ArrayFormula` in front, the calculation is shown only where the data is, but the result is always equal to the result of first row.

Can anyone help me?

You can [view my sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkKaHeBdxneDdHNNQUY5elliWnZRcEVEdkZpZ2h4S1E&usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the magic of matrix multiplication and [this solution](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/mgfGOYDzAQw/qGfazAKqFrkJ) (credit where credit is due), I have managed to wrangle it to do what you want.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF( J4:J = "" ; "" ; MMULT((ROW(G4:G)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(G3:G)))*((ROW(G4:G)+1-I4:I)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(G3:G)));G3:G)* ( ( J4:J ) / 10 ) ))
```

My head hurts already, so I won't go into too much explanatory detail, except to say that the key magic happens in

```
="MMULT((ROW(Range1)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(Range2)))*((ROW(Range1)+1-I4:I)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(Range2)));Range2)))"
```

And I've added a second sheet to your public one with a rough equation builder, for understanding or alternative applications.

Comment: You're welcome. And I'll make you deliver on that offer one day.